# pyqt4: how to see QWebPage?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I am new at QT, found some code that do what I need (some web-browsing things), it uses QWebPage to get get pages, but it does not make windows to see it. I tried to use example from Russian wiki (it works):

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
application = QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QWidget()

widget.resize(320, 240)
widget.setWindowTitle("Hello, World!")  
widget.show()

sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

And this points: QWebPage inherit QObject, QObject inherit QWidget

but for

```
browser = QWebPage()
browser.show()
```

I get `AttributeError: 'QWebPage' object has no attribute 'show'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> QObject inherits QWidget

No, It doesn't - `QWidget` inherits `QObject`, not the other way around. `QWebPage` is just a data object. You need a [QWebView](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebview.html) which inherits `QWidget` and is the widget used for displaying QWebPages:

```
browser = QWebView()
browser.show()
```